# Way to use CMake to generate header/code based on contents of a directory?

Tags: c++, cmake

Say I have a class “base”, and in a subdirectory “dir” I have “foo”, “bar”, and “leg”, each with a header and a source file and inheriting “base”, like this.

```
-base.hpp/cpp
-dir
  |-foo.hpp/cpp
  |-bar.hpp/cpp
  |-leg.hpp/cpp
```

I was wondering if there was a way with Cmake to find the headers in “dir”, include them in a file, and then take the names (without the extension) and then generate code, so that the resulting files would be something like:

dir_files.hpp -

```
 #include “dir/foo.hpp”
 #include “dir/bar.hpp”
 #include “dir/leg.hpp”
 void function();
```

dir_files.cpp -

```
 #include “dir_files.hpp”
 void function() 
 {
  do_something(foo);
  do_something(bar);
  do_something(leg);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, this seems acheivable. Have you looked at the CMake documentation (e.g., the [`file` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/file.html))?. What exactly is the problem you're having? I doubt anyone is going to write the script for you...

Comment: I'm really a noob with CMake. I don't quite understand it's syntax and I was wanting for somebody to recommend some commands that would be of use here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following keywords/ techniques:

CMake:

```
# "file" to find all files relative to your root location
file(GLOB SRC_H
  RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  "dir/*.h"
)

file(GLOB SRC_CPP
  RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  "dir/*.cpp"
)

# foreach to iterate through all files
foreach(SRC_H_FILE ${SRC_H})
  message("header ${SRC_H_FILE}")

  # You could build up your include part here
  set(INCLUDE_PART "${INCLUDE_PART}#include <${SRC_H_FILE}>\n")
endforeach()

foreach(SRC_CPP_FILE ${SRC_CPP})
  message("src ${SRC_CPP_FILE}")
endforeach()

message("${INCLUDE_PART}")

# Configure expands variables in a template file
configure_file(
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/HeaderTemplate.h.in.cmake"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/HeaderTemplate.h"
)
```

HeaderTemplate.h.in.cmake:

```
// Template file

@INCLUDE_PART@
void function();
```

The CMake output would be:

Log:

```
header dir/Test1.h
header dir/Test2.h
header dir/Test3.h
src dir/Test1.cpp
src dir/Test2.cpp
src dir/Test3.cpp
#include <dir/Test1.h>
#include <dir/Test2.h>
#include <dir/Test3.h>
```

HeaderTemplate.h

```
// Template file

#include <dir/Test1.h>
#include <dir/Test2.h>
#include <dir/Test3.h>

void function();
```

Comment: This seems like a good way to solve the problem. I guess there isn't any specific function to do that, but I guess it would be a niche function anyway.

Comment: For the "generate code" part, I used the STRING REPLACE command to remove the file extension.

Comment: @MamaLuigi Yes, this functionality seems too specific to be expected to built into CMake. However, you can always create your own [`function`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/function.html) or [`macro`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/macro.html).

Comment: @Mama Luigi `get_filename_component` offers the possibility to get various filename components like the extension or the filename

Comment: @Denis Blank Thanks. I did use that command in the final solution.